# Resources about crash-safe and fault-tolerance programming

Tags: c++, crash, posix, fault-tolerance

I like the LWN article ["Crash-only software"](http://lwn.net/Articles/191059/) and I would like to learn more about crash-safe and fault-tolerant programming.

It is surprisingly hard to assure that the persistent state is consistent in fault situations. Here I do not even talk about distributed operations: That is hard on a single node, too: Even the normal Berkeley DB (BDB Data Store or BDB Concurrent Data Store) might have a destroyed database if the system crashes. Not only that high level application constraints are broken, the database might not be opened correctly if the system crashes.

What are good resources about crash-safe and fault-tolerant designs, approaches, and programming.

If the resources focus on C++ and POSIX environments, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Side note: in the latest Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) the OS just sends a SIGKILL to all applications which are in a supposedly 'clean' state. Impressive how this really results in a 1-second shutdown (on a newer machine, I must admit). Reference: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008898-SW22

Answer (score 6):

Akka is a framework for Java and Scala that is written with let-it-crash in mind. See this [article](http://jonasboner.com/introducing-akka/) and [this](http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/162) presentation for an introduction to Actors and let-it-crash. It is also called [Fail-Fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) and [worker/supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html) style.

Two good presentations on erlang is [Systems that Never Stop (and Erlang)](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Systems-that-Never-Stop-Joe-Armstrong) and [Message Passing Concurrency in Erlang](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Message-Passing-Concurrency)

[Theron](http://theron.ashtonmason.net/index.php) is a actor library for C++, I also think there is something in Boost also.

Also Erlang can call C or C++ [code](http://erlang.org/euc/03/proceedings/1400Hal.ppt) see this for a discussion. Java / Scala / Akka can also call C++ code.

(If you like C++ I suggest you to have a look at Scala, very nice language and better than Java if you come from C++.)

Also Jonas Boners presentation [Scalability, Availability & Stability Patterns](http://www.slideshare.net/jboner/scalability-availability-stability-patterns) is a good presentation on the topic.

Comment: If you let Java (or Scala) call a C++ DLL by using JNI, then the stability of the JVM is endangered. Since the C++ code runs in the same process as the JVM, the JVM will die if you get a crash in the C++ code. JNI does not work very well, do not use it.

Comment: JNI/JNA works great if you understand the complexities involved.  Crashing your JVM because the C code you called seg faulted isn't JNI's fault.

Answer (score 1):

The Aktor model in languages Erlang and Scala the let it crash model. See this [article](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/05/19/37819/).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above set of answers, there is [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) and [GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/), which has been missed out. Of course this is not C++.

There is another experimental library in C++ called [libcppa](https://github.com/Neverlord/libcppa). [Theron](http://www.theron-library.com/index.php) is more mature than this.

Any way your best bet is to use either:

1. Erlang
2. Scala / Akka

Comment: Do you know if Theron supports Scala-like remote actors?

Comment: Theron does not support remote actors, but [libcppa does](http://neverlord.github.com/libcppa/manual/index_0_3_3.html#htoc47).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement fault tolerance features in C++, basically you will rewrite Erlang. Don't reinvent the wheel, Erlang OTP is there and battle tested for 35+ years. Use it!.